# theory behind rotation of a 3d cube using mouse

Tags: 3d, python, pygame

I want to rotate a 3d cube using mouse in python/pygame. Could someone explain the theory behind rotating a 3d cube by mouse?

I dont understand how angleX, angleY and angleZ are affected by mouse rotation on 2d. I know it involves sin,cos etc on the mouse's relative movement but dont know exactly about them.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you don't understand? I'm sure you understand the general theory of "move mouse->rotate cube". How the cube rotates is a style thing that varies between implementation. Tell us what you've tried, exactly what you want, and how what you've tried doesn't match what you want.

Comment: @Byte56, I REALLY need someone's help. If you want more data, I can provide you. Even the source code, but PLEASE HELP ME !! [This is my current code.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vhbc17ennexycb/rotating_cube.py). You may give hints to me or modify the code yourself. I know its easy and getting lots of -1s because I don't know how to ask them well but I think my question is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Start by learning how to rotate an object around an arbitrary axis, for this you might check out [a simple rotation example someone has already implemented](http://www.pygame.org/project-Rotating+3D+Cube-1859-.html). Since the mouse only moves in two dimensions, and there are three dimensions available for rotation, you'll have to decide how you want map those two dimensions to three dimensions of rotation.

One of the simpler strategies is to use the camera axis to rotate the object. Essentially, regardless of the orientation of the cube, you will always rotate it as if it had the same axis orientation as your camera. So, moving the mouse left or right rotates around the y axis, up/down around the x axis. Sometimes people will implement something like holding a modifier key, then moving the mouse to rotate around the z axis.